# Проверка пользователя, есть ли он в базе

Tags: php

```
$c_e = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users where name='".$_POST ["name"]."'")); {if ($c_e>0) {$errm .= "Логин занят"; $error=1;}}
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: А что за ошибка? Я, кроме назревающей `SQL injection`, ничего не увидел.

Comment: ? какая инфекция?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string до запроса, а вообще причин почему бы код мог не выполнятся я не вижу... Что именно не работает то?

Comment: @Prikol, похоже, вам не помешает ознакомиться с этой темой: [На какие уязвимости, помимо SQL-инъекций и XSS, стоит проверить сайт?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/39575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явно дурной тон) Попробуй так:

```
$name= mysql_escape_string($_POST ["name"]);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users where name='$name'");
$c_e = mysql_num_rows($res); 
if ($c_e>0) {
$errm .= "Логин занят"; 
$error=1;
}
```

P.S. "Какая инфекция?" - ахахахахаха